# "Find Usages" shows wrong results for class methods

Tags: typescript, webstorm

If I define a class like:

```
export class MyTestClass {
  public toggle() { // *
    return true;
  }
}

// * I changes the value to `toggle`, 
// because this name is used often in libs, 
// so the described behaviour might be easier to reproduce.
```

**What I do**

select `testMethod` and click on `Edit | Find | Find Usages`.

**Expected behaviour**
All occurrences of `MyTestClass.testMethod` are listed in the result set

**Actual behaviour**
All occurrences of `testMethod` are listed, even ones **NOT** related to `MyTestClass`.

**My question**
Is there a way to tell *WebStorm* to only show class related method usages?

Comment: Found this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-3829 but this option does not exist in WebStorm 2019.1.2 anymore.

Comment: **Weaker type guess for completion** has been replaced with **Only type-based completion** (**Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript**), but it only affects completion and doesn't work when searching for usages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue looks similar to [WEB-35855](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35855), please follow it for updates

Comment: Thanks, seemingly the same root problem. I started watching this issue.

Comment: Accepted answer, because WEB-35855 is fixed in WebStorm 2019.2